# Delete end of array empty PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have a array explode script. and i have a empty in end lines off array .
i done try array_filter, unset and array_splice. but this still not working
maybe can someone help my problem

[image]

```
Array
(
    [0] => QRIS,09:31
    [1] => QRIS-13f74bcf-811
    [2] => axxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    [4] => Rp.275,537
    [5] => settlement
)
Array
(
    [0] => QRIS,08:52
    [1] => QRIS-9ebf94b4-79d
    [2] => sxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    [4] => Rp.90,842
    [5] => settlement
)
Array
(
    [0] => QRIS,07:47
    [1] => QRIS-15504cb6-012
    [2] => ixxxxxx@gmail.com
    [4] => Rp.211,927
    [5] => settlement
)
Array
(
)
```

i want like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => QRIS,09:31
    [1] => QRIS-13f74bcf-811
    [2] => axxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    [4] => Rp.275,537
    [5] => settlement
)
Array
(
    [0] => QRIS,08:52
    [1] => QRIS-9ebf94b4-79d
    [2] => sxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    [4] => Rp.90,842
    [5] => settlement
)
Array
(
    [0] => QRIS,07:47
    [1] => QRIS-15504cb6-012
    [2] => ixxxxxx@gmail.com
    [4] => Rp.211,927
    [5] => settlement
)
```

thanks before and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Post you current code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unset` for all empty arrays.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
 if ($value == []) {
  unset($data[$key]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_pop` in order to remove the last element like:

```
array_pop($array);
```

If you want to remove all empty items use `array_filter`:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($el) {return !empty($el);});
```